# 〜みたい / 〜らしい grammar difference

Tags: word-choice, nuances

correct example:
「うちの子には子供らしく元気に育ってほしい。」

why is it not correct?
「うちの子には子供みたいに元気に育ってほしい。」

can't really understand why it can't be used in this sentence

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that:

「こども**らしい**」 has a **positive** meaning of "**child-like**" and

「こども**みたい**」 has a **negative** meaning of "**childish**".

Thus, your second sentence:

> 「うちの子{こ}には子供{こども}**みたい**に元気{げんき}に育{そだ}ってほしい。」

practically makes no sense as it means:

> "I want my kid to grow up healthily in a childish way."

Your first sentnece:

> 「うちの子には子供**らしく**元気に育ってほしい。」

makes perfect sense as it means:

> "I want my kid to grow up healthily like a good kid (should)."

Comment: This is an interesting difference between these two words. Does it apply more generally, or just to  this example?

Comment: 大人らしく⇔ (usu. a young person) behave like an adult, be mature (good),  大人みたい ⇔ (usu. a teenager) look like an adult (good/neutral), お爺さんらしく  ⇔ (needs more, e,g, ゆっくりあるく、知恵が深い), お爺さんみたい  ⇔ (needs more, ...), 自分らしく ⇔ being oneself (good), 自分みたい⇔  (needs more, ...),

Comment: @Locksleyu ～みたい is not always negative. Saying プロみたい to an amateur sport player is definitely positive (and saying the same thing to a real professional player is either insulting or playful).

Comment: 子供みたい is not always negative, either. 私の母は子供みたいに笑う does not carry any negative connotation, and saying 私の母は子供らしく笑う sounds simply unnatural.